# Angle in a triangle with bisectors

Tags: geometry

The line segments AD, BD and CD are bisectors in $\triangle ABC$ where D is the intersection point of the bisectors. $\angle BDC$ is $128^\circ$. How big is $\angle BAC$ ?

The answer is $76^\circ$. But how to get that?

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My guess: The question is: How can one show the angle at A is 76 degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $1.$ Because $\angle BDC$ is $128^\circ$, $\angle DBC$ and $\angle DCB$ add up to ??

$2.$ The lines $BD$ and $CD$ are angle bisectors. Thus from ($1$) we conclude that $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ACB$ add up to ??

$3.$ Thus $\angle BAC$ is ??

Comment: I fixed a slight typo...

Comment: Thank you. There was only one?